# Javascript: Check string to match pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to test string weather it matches a specific pattern.
String is the full file path, for example: 
`C:\some\path\to\folder\folder.jpg`
or
`C:\another\file\path\file.jpg`

Pattern is: file name without extension should match exact parent folder name, where it is located. File name could be any possible value.

So, in my example only first string matches pattern:

> C:\some\path\to\**folder**\**folder**.jpg

Can this test be made in javascript using one regular expression?

Comment: In your example `folder.jpg` does have an extention of `.jpg`. How is condition _file name without extension should match exact parent folder name, where it is located_ satisfied here ?

Comment: try using indexOf method var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, with a *back reference*:

```
\\([^\\]+)\\\1\.[^.\\]*$
```

The first group `([^\\]+)` captures the folder name, then the back reference (`\1`) refers back to it saying "the same thing here."

So in the above, we have:

- `\\` - matches a literal backslash
- `([^\\]+)` - the capture group for the folder name
- `\\` - another literal backslash
- `\1` - the back reference to the capture group saying "same thing here"
- `\.` - a literal `.` (to introduce the extension)
- `[^.\\]*` - zero or more extension chars (you may want to change `*` to `+` to mean "one or more")
- `$` - end of string

[On regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zC3qS3/1)

If you consider `C:\some\path\to\folder\folder.test.jpg` a valid match (e.g., you think of the extension on `folder.test.jpg` as being `.test.jpg`, not `.jpg`), just remove the `.` from the `[^.\\]` near the end.

If you want to allow for files without an extension, perhaps `\\([^\\]+)\\\1(?:\.[^.\\]+)?$`. The `(?:\.[^.\\]+)?` is the optional extension.

Comment: I thinky you should add the dot to the last negated character class, otherwise it would match e.g. `\folder\folder.test.jpg`

Comment: @SebastianProske: You're right, I've fixed it. Although I suppose it depends on your definition of "extension" (is the extension `.jpg` or `.test.jpg`). I agree with yours, though.